# laarvel query builder output is messy

Tags: php, laravel, query-builder

I'm new to laravel framework and I faced this problem , when I send a query Get the results in this form :

```
[{"visitors":3}]
```

here is the code I used to get this result :

```
<?php echo $q = DB::table('visitors')->select('visitors')->get(); ?>
```

is there something that I missed ?

Comment: You don't get the results in that form, you get them in that form if you JSON encode them. What's your expected form?

Comment: I needed it raw (just 3 in this case)
I solved it with explode function but it is not the best solution

Comment: Use `value("visitors")` instead of `get()`

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best practice

```
<?php echo $q = DB::table('visitors')->select('visitors')->get(); ?>
```

Following the MVC pattern, you should query in your controller, like

```
$q = DB::table('visitors')->select('visitors')->get();
```

then pass `$q` it in your view. Then loop through `$q` to get all results. If you need any specific result, like `$id = 3`, then use where.